# How can I extract the correct data for the variables X2 and Y2 in the following python code?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
thread_list = ['DWr','Idle','MulWr','Lock']
Target_list = ['0','0','0','1']
trd_coor = [26,10,51,10,226,10,251,10]
mem_coor = [10,215,35,215,60,215,85,215,210,215,235,215,260,215,285,215]
targ_1 = ['write-back','uncachable-high']
count_dash_T_list = [0,1,2,3]
count_T = 0
count_X1 = 0
count_Y1 = 0
count_target = 0
count_target_1 = 0
count_dash_T = 0
T = []
trd_Y1 = []
count_dash_T_list = []

for i in trd_coor[1::2]:
    Y1 = i
    trd_Y1.append(Y1)


            
for i in range(0,len(count_dash_T_list)):
    print(i)
    target = Target_list[count_target]
    count_target += 1
    
    for i in targ_1:
        if (target == '0'):
            if (i == 'write-back'):
                X2 = mem_coor[0]
                Y2 = mem_coor[1]
            elif (i == 'uncachable-high'):
                X2 = mem_coor[2]
                Y2 = mem_coor[3]
            elif (i == 'write-through'):
                X2 = mem_coor[4]
                Y2 = mem_coor[5]
            elif (i == 'write-combining'):
                X2 = mem_coor[6]
                Y2 = mem_coor[7]
        elif (target == '1'):
            if (i == 'write-high'):
                X2 = mem_coor[8]
                Y2 = mem_coor[9]
            elif (i == 'uncachable-high'):
                X2 = mem_coor[10]
                Y2 = mem_coor[11]
            elif (i == 'write-through'):
                X2 = mem_coor[12]
                Y2 = mem_coor[13]
            elif (i == 'write-combining'):
                X2 = mem_coor[14]
                Y2 = mem_coor[15]
                                
    print(X2)
    print(Y2)
    arrow_thread = thread_list[count_T]
    #print(arrow_thread)
    arrow_X1 = trd_coor[count_X1]
    #print(arrow_X1)
    arrow_Y1 = trd_Y1[count_Y1]
    #print(arrow_Y1)
    count_T += 1
    count_X1 += 2
    count_Y1 += 1               
    arrow = '<g> <line x1="{}" y1="{}" x2="{}" y2="{}" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" /><text x="0" y="0" font-family="Verdana" font-size="5" fill="black">{}</text> </g>'.format(arrow_X1,arrow_Y1,X2,Y2,arrow_thread)
    #print(arrow)
```

The code takes the length of the dash T list that has 4 items and iterates through the target list then for each memory type in this case write-back or uncachable it looks at what the target number is and prints the X2 and Y2 variable.

For the following code I'm getting the following output:

```
 0,
35,
215,
1,
35,
215,
2,
35,
215,
3,
235,
215
```

and I want the output to be:

```
0,
10,
215,
1,
10,
215,
2,
10,
215,
3,
235,
215
```

How can I rearrange my code so that the desired output is possible? Or any debug tips?
Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what your code is doing but maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: it could be simpler to use one line `for target in Target_list:` instead of three lines `for i in range(0,len(count_dash_T_list)):` and `target = Target_list[count_target]` and `count_target += 1`

Comment: this code doesn't even work because you defined `count_dash_T_list = []`

Comment: if you change order in list `targ_1 = ['uncachable-high', 'write-back']` then you get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your code is doing but if you change order in list

```
targ_1 = ['uncachable-high', 'write-back']
```

then you get expected result.

---

Minimal working code

```
target_list = ['0','0','0','1']

mem_coor = [10,215,35,215,60,215,85,215,210,215,235,215,260,215,285,215]
targ_1 = ['uncachable-high', 'write-back']

for number, target in enumerate(target_list):
    print('--- number:', number, '| taget:', target, '---')
    
    print(number)
    
    for i in targ_1:
        if target == '0':
            if i == 'write-back':
                X2 = mem_coor[0]
                Y2 = mem_coor[1]
            elif i == 'uncachable-high':
                X2 = mem_coor[2]
                Y2 = mem_coor[3]
            elif i == 'write-through':
                X2 = mem_coor[4]
                Y2 = mem_coor[5]
            elif i == 'write-combining':
                X2 = mem_coor[6]
                Y2 = mem_coor[7]
        elif target == '1':
            if i == 'write-high':
                X2 = mem_coor[8]
                Y2 = mem_coor[9]
            elif i == 'uncachable-high':
                X2 = mem_coor[10]
                Y2 = mem_coor[11]
            elif i == 'write-through':
                X2 = mem_coor[12]
                Y2 = mem_coor[13]
            elif i == 'write-combining':
                X2 = mem_coor[14]
                Y2 = mem_coor[15]
                                
    print(X2)
    print(Y2)
```

Result:

```
--- number: 0 | taget: 0 ---
0
10
215
--- number: 1 | taget: 0 ---
1
10
215
--- number: 2 | taget: 0 ---
2
10
215
--- number: 3 | taget: 1 ---
3
235
215
```